# QTcpSocket write variables

Tags: qt, sockets

I'm new to Qt and I'm trying to create a simple IRC bot.
I connect to server and I can read and write. But I'd like to write variables.

```
socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
//connection here
socket->write("I want to send a variable");
```

I've tried printf-like syntax:

```
socket->("I want to send a %s", variable);
```

But it doesn't work.

Is it possible to send a variable in one line?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to wrap it in a [QDataStream](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html) and use that to serialize your messages.  It'll make your life a lot easier.  You should check out these (complete) examples for details:

- [Fortune Client Example](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneclient.html)
- [Fortune Server Example](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneserver.html)

Hope that helps!